# Memory efficient way to read an array of integers from single line of input in python2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I want to read a single line of input containing integers separated by spaces.
Currently I use the following.

```
A = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

But now the N is around 10^5 and I don't need the whole array of integers, I just need to read them 1 at a time, in the same sequence as the input.

Can you suggest an efficient way to do this in Python2.7

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the data a character at a time, this would reduce memory usage:

```
data = "1 50 30 1000   20 4 1 2"

number = []
numbers = []

for c in data:
    if c == ' ':
        if number:
            numbers.append(int(''.join(number)))
            number = []
    else:
        number.append(c)

if number:
    numbers.append(int(''.join(number)))

print numbers
```

Giving you:

```
[1, 50, 30, 1000, 20, 4, 1, 2]
```

Probably quite a bit slower though.

---

Alternatively, you could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to read groups of digits as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = "1 50 30 1000   20 4 1 2"
numbers = []

for k, g in groupby(data, lambda c: c.isdigit()):
    if k:
        numbers.append(int(''.join(g)))

print numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

Use generators:

```
numbers = '1 2 5 18 10 12 16 17 22 50'
gen = (int(x) for x in numbers.split())
for g in gen:
    print g


1
5
6
8
10
12
68
13
```

the generator object would use one item at a time, and won't construct a whole list.

Comment: `split()` is not a generator, so it will first produce a complete list of textual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to destroy the original string, split accepts a parameter for the maximum number of breaks.

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) for more details and examples.